# How to replace div with one of its child p nodes

Tags: php, regex

This html I get from the Response.

And I need to remove the extra text.

There is a line of the following content

```
<?php
    $str = <<<HTML
    AAAA <span>span txt</span>
    <div class='unique_div' id='xrz' data-id='1'>
        div text
        <span>span text</span>
        <p class='unique_p'>
            <span>p span text</span>
            <p>p p text</p>
        </p>
        div text
    </div>
    BBBB <span>span txt</span>
HTML;
```

How to replace div on p which is inside it?

I need to write a regular expression to get the following result

```
<?php
    $str = <<<HTML
    AAAA <span>span txt</span>
    <p class='unique_p'>
        <span>p span text</span>
        <p>p p text</p>
    </p>
    BBBB <span>span txt</span>
HTML;
```

There is only one div and p with such attributes.

Comment: We dont understand. Do you mean you want to change the contents is `$str` after you have created the first example into the second example?

Comment: I need to get a result as in the second example

Comment: Why? Just create a seperate output based on whatever reason you want to amend it

Comment: `IF ($reason) {$str=example1} else {$str=example2}`

Comment: This html I get from the query.And I need to remove the extra text

Comment: @RiggsFolly I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking at what appears to be HTML and given that your requirements entail some form of modification to the [Document Object Model (*DOM*)](https://www.w3.org/DOM/) I would suggest using a DOM parser like [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument).

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking to replace the `<div>` node which appears to have an `id` attribute of `xrz` with the `p` node that has a class attribute of `unique_p` and is **a child of the `div`**.

1. Getting the `div` is easy, because it has an `id` and they are unique. So we can use a method like [`DOMDocument::getElementById`](http://php.net/domdocument.getelementbyid) to get that `div`.
2. Getting its child `p` gets a little trickier since we want to make sure it's both a child of `div` and has the specified class. So we'll rely on an [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) query for that using [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/domxpath).
3. Finally, we'll replace the `div` with its captured child `p` by using [`DOMNode::replaceChild`](http://php.net/domnode.replacechild) from there.

Here's a simple example.

```
$str = <<<HTML
    AAAA <span>span txt</span>
    <div class='unique_div' id='xrz' data-id='1'>
        div text
        <span>span text</span>
        <p class='unique_p'>
            <span>p span text</span>
            <p>p p text</p>
        </p>
        div text
    </div>
    BBBB <span>span txt</span>
HTML;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$children = $xpath->query('//div/p[@class="unique_p"]');
$p = $children->item(0);
$div = $dom->getElementById('xrz');
$div->parentNode->replaceChild($p, $div);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The output should look something like this.

```
<p>AAAA <span>span txt</span>
    <p class="unique_p">
            <span>p span text</span>
            </p><p>
    BBBB <span>span txt</span></p></p>
```

In case you're wondering why the output may appear slightly different than what you might expect, it's important to note that your initial HTML, provided in your question, is actually malformed.

[See section 9.3.1 of the HTML 4.01 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

> The `P` element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (*including `P` itself*).

So each time a DOM parser finds an opening `p` tag inside of another `p` tag it will just implicitly close the previous one first.

Comment: Wow.Perfect solution.Thank you very much

Comment: You should also specify `div` class attribute while running a query.

Comment: @revo That is unnecessary since an `id` must be unique throughout the entire DOM according to the spec. The `id` is enough to uniquely identify any element in the DOM without further qualification.

Comment: Sorry, I looked at the XPath query expecting `div[@class="unique_div"]` or `div[@id="xrz"]` and missed the line where you specified it later `getElementById()`.

Comment: I see. I tried clarifying what the code does above in **bullet 2**